# Loading gif for a winform

Tags: winforms, loading, gif

Loading gif for a winform, when i click a button i need to show loading gif then after some action it should not be displayed.

I can find tutorial for web form, but am struggling to do the same for winform, pls. suggest some idea.

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 11):

The standard `PictureBox` control can display animated GIFs.

Make a `PictureBox` on your form, set its `Image` property to an animated GIF, and set its `Visible` property to `false`.

Then, when you want to perform your action, set the `PictureBox`'s `Visible` property to `true` in code, perform the action, and set it to `false` again.

Note that if you perform your action on the UI thread, the form, including the animation, will freeze until it finishes.  To solve this, look at the `BackgroundWorker` component.